# Does "improve non functional requirement" mean: move to codereview?

Tags: discussion, migration

I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625022/count-the-minimum-number-of-jumps-required-for-a-frog-to-get-to-the-other-side-o) this morning. The title and problem description might be a bit lengthy, but overall, I think this is a good question (basically about an optimisation problem).

In essence, the question gives working code and asks for performance improvements. Of course, one can quickly argue "working code belongs on code review", but well: when code doesn't meet a nonfunctional requirements (such as: its too slow), is it really working?

I saw the CR [guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) on that subject, and reading that I *think* that question would fit the CR community.

But still I am wondering: is the original question off-topic here (for that specific reason)?

Comment: "when code doesn't meet a nonfunctional requirements (such as: its too slow), is it really working?". Hm. Well, my opinion would be that it is in fact not working when  clearly defined requirements are not met. That has little bearing on the quality of a question, however. Although the question seems okay to me, I don't really see much value in it for other people.

Comment: @Gimby Sure. But my focus isn't the quality of the specific question I linked to. It is more about the best practice when reviewing them, if "turn to codereview" is the correct action to take.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes. I'm trying to reason if the question is truly off-topic on Stack Overflow, because if it isn't then migration is not really a good idea unless the author wants it to happen themselves. On top of that recently I've been made aware of the aspect that when thinking about a migration you should more worry about the migration of the answer. Does code review want that answer which is already there?

Answer (score 3):

> *"when code doesn't meet a nonfunctional requirements (such as: its too slow), is it really working?"*

By that logic, you could add any requirement to working code to make it "on-topic" here.

But yes, the original question is a textbook code-review and should be posted there. It's off-topic on SO.

Comment: Performance isn't some obscure made up argument. It is about solving a specific problem, isn't it. It is not about the having some requirements, it is about a solution not working given a specific goal.

Comment: @GhostCat: How does one fix performance issues? By _reviewing_ your code and subsequently rewriting it. This is similar to _"best practice"_ questions, they're off-topic as well.

Comment: Strongly disagree. Improving performance is a well-defined requirement and isn't opinion-based. You can consider big-O complexity as well as measure performance directly to determine whether a goal is achieved. IMO, it's good practice in such questions that some *measure* of improvement is *quantified*, e.g. move from O(n**2) to O(n log n), or 1hr to < 10mins, etc.

Comment: @jpp: but if the question only says _"it's not good enough"_, then it really isn't on-topic here.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I agree with that. I just feel your answer with the single quote (without context) is misleading. Performance questions are not *necessarily* out-of-scope, but *may well be* if not carefully worded. Some of the best answers on SO IMO are performance-related.

Comment: @jpp: my answer is discussing the question the OP linked to. That's a textbook code-review. The quote is basically what this meta question boils down to.

Comment: That question was merely an example. I was more interested in the "overall philosophy here).